# compare()-method behaves weirdly on Chrome, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I just have no idea why my sorting algorithm works fine on Safari and Firefox, but not on Chrome.

What I'm trying to do is, sort items (a and b) depending on the order of their itemType properties in the sortingOrder array. Also, within each group of items of a given itemType, visible items should come first, invisible ones behind.

The sorting of the itemTypes works fine, everywhere, but Chrome always mixes up visible and invisible items.

Does anybody have an idea why?

Didn't feel that stuck for quite some time..

```
SomeClass.prototype.sortItems = function () 
{
    var self = this;
    this.items.sort(function(a, b) { return self.compare(a, b); });
};

SomeClass.prototype.compare = function (a, b) 
{
    if (a.itemType == b.itemType)
        return (!a.visible && b.visible)? 1 : (a.visible && !b.visible)? -1 : 0;
    else
        return this.sortingOrder.indexOf(a.itemType) - this.sortingOrder.indexOf(b.itemType);
};
```

Comment: Have an example of your items in which it does not work?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I probably should have said that I'm using the Phaser game engine. Items are instances of a class extending Phaser.Image. They definitely do have 'visible' and 'itemType' properties, and I already logged them inside that method to make sure they are correctly set, which they are.

Comment: Try running a small sample and console log a, b and what you will return inside compare method to check its really returning what it should